# In Psalm 27:6 is there a historic or prophetic reason David is confident that "now" is when he will triumph?

Tags: psalms, prophecy, david, messiah

David's life was marked by a long period of being on the run, defeated and so on. However in this Psalm he seems to very confident that the time has come for him to triumph over his enemies. Does this Psalm relate to some particular event in his life where God had assured him of his imminent victory or is this prophetic of some time in the future when the messiah will reach victory?

I ask this because this isn't so much a "wish" or a "hope" but a confident assertion that the time of triumph has arrived.

In other words, this doesn't seem to be an all-purpose prayer for any occasion but rather a celebration of soon to be accomplished victory and I'm wondering if we can relate this to any particular event.

> NET Bible Psalm 27 By David. 1The Lord delivers and vindicates me! I
>   fear no one! The Lord protects my life! I am afraid of no one! 2When
>   evil men attack me to devour my flesh, when my adversaries and enemies
>   attack me, they stumble and fall. 3Even when an army is deployed
>   against me, I do not fear. Even when war is imminent, I remain
>   confident. 4I have asked the Lord for one thing – this is what I
>   desire! I want to live in the Lord’s house all the days of my life, so
>   I can gaze at the splendor of the Lord and contemplate in his temple.
>   5He will surely give me shelter in the day of danger; he will hide me
>   in his home; he will place me on an inaccessible rocky summit. 6**Now
>   I will triumph over my enemies who surround me!** I will offer
>   sacrifices in his dwelling place and shout for joy! I will sing
>   praises to the Lord! 7Hear me, O Lord, when I cry out! Have mercy on
>   me and answer me! 8My heart tells me to pray to you, and I do pray to
>   you, O Lord. 9Do not reject me! Do not push your servant away in
>   anger! You are my deliverer! Do not forsake or abandon me, O God who
>   vindicates me! 10Even if my father and mother abandoned me, the Lord
>   would take me in. 11Teach me how you want me to live; lead me along a
>   level path because of those who wait to ambush me! 12Do not turn me
>   over to my enemies, for false witnesses who want to destroy me testify
>   against me. 13**Where would I be if I did not believe I would
>   experience the Lord’s favor in the land of the living?** 14Rely on the
>   Lord! Be strong and confident! Rely on the Lord! NET Bible copyright ©
>   1996-2006 by Biblical Studies Press, L.L.C. http://netbible.com. Used
>   by permission. All rights reserved.

Why "now"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no title to the Psalm, nor is there anything within it that would place it in a known context in David's life and varied circumstances. There is no information in the text at all to link it to any historic event. It would be sheer conjecture to simply guess at what time the Psalm occurred. We just don't know.

Except for the first verse of the Psalm.

> The Lord is my light, and my salvation. The Lord is the strength of my life. [KJV]

It is this that gives David such confidence in the remainder of the Psalm. It is this that is the basis of his trust and his hope.

That he knows the Lord. That he is conscious of the Lord's presence and support. That he knows, within himself, that the Lord is shining upon him, irradiating him with clear light, saving him - now, as he speaks the words - and giving him strength within himself.